# Use Linux dd to copy and read file at specified location

Tags: linux, dd

I have destination drive which I know is partitioned in 512b sectors. I want to transfer let's say 150b file with **dd** to this drive at a given destination, let's say start sector 2099200, and then to read exactly the same amount of bytes as the file size (150b) from the same location sector. I tried something like this:

**sudo dd if=my.txt of=/dev/sdb obs=512 seek=2099199**

**sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=my.txt obs=150 count=1 ibs=512 skip=2099199**

It almost works but I can't make it transfer only 150b:

*1+0 records in
3+1 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied*

What is wrong and how to do what I need? May be I get it wrong and some other solution would be better, but I need to be file system independent.

Comment: It's probably due to 512b block size.

Answer (score 2):

From the `man` page:

```
count=BLOCKS
   copy only BLOCKS input blocks
```

When you copy the file back from the drive, you are copying 512 bytes because you specify the input to be copied in 512 byte blocks with the `ibs` option and you copy one whole block with the `count` option. Instead, you could just specify the number of blocks you wish to copy as your `ibs` value:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=my.txt ibs=150 count=1 skip=2099199
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this method would require recomputing the skip value. An alternative would be this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=512 count=1 skip=2099199 | dd count=150 of=my.txt
```

Comment: Except with a different `ibs`, the `skip` number needs to be recalculated, too, and there's no guarantee that the particular input block he wants is aligned...

Comment: It worked but like this: sudo dd if=/dev/sdb ibs=512 count=1 skip=2099199 | dd ibs=150 count=1 of=my.txt